# react.js how can I autofocus a contentEditable element

Tags: reactjs, contenteditable, autofocus

How can I set focus on a contentEditable element in react?
I have found a lot pages anout the subjet, but cant get it to work.

Sample code:

```
import React, { useRef, useEffect } from 'react';

const About = () => {
    const inputRef = useRef(null);

    useEffect(inputRef => {
        if (inputRef) {
            inputRef.focus();
        }
    }, []);

    return (
        <div className="about">
            <h2>About</h2>

            <p className="paragraph"
                contentEditable={true}
                suppressContentEditableWarning={true}
                spellCheck={false}
                ref={inputRef}
            >
                Hello
            </p>

        </div >
    )
}

export default About;
```

Comment: The problem I guess is that when the useEffect is executed maybe input ref is null. My 2 suggestions is that one change the useEffect to useLayoutEffect and also change the focus to inputRef.current.focus()

Comment: It didnt work changing these 2 parameters. Maybe I should make a class-component instead.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Looks like my solution is this.

```
 import React, { useRef, useEffect } from 'react';

const About = () => {
    const inputRef = useRef(null);

    useEffect(() => {
        inputRef.current.focus();
    }, [inputRef]);

    return (
        <div className="about">
            <h2>About</h2>

            <p className="paragraph"
                contentEditable={true}
                suppressContentEditableWarning={true}
                spellCheck={false}
                ref={inputRef}
            >
                Hello
            </p>

        </div >
    )
}

export default About;
```

Comment: how to apply this in class component?

Answer (score 1):

Found another working solution:

```
const inputRef = useCallback(node => {
    node.focus()
  }, [])
```

Answer (score 0):

May be you can use this:

```
  <textarea className="paragraph"
             ref={inputRef}
             value={yourValueState}
            autofocus/>
```

Comment: But then I loose the possibilities of a contentEditable element.